# Fail to define an infinite stream

Tags: haskell, stream, lazy-evaluation

I'm working on [UPENN Haskell Homework 6 Exercise 5](http://www.seas.upenn.edu/%7Ecis194/spring13/hw/06-laziness.pdf), trying to define a `ruler function`

`0,1,0,2,0,1,0,3,0,1,0,2,0,1,0,4,...`

where the nth element in the stream (assuming the first element corresponds to `n` = 1) is the largest `power of 2` which evenly divides `n`.

I just came up with an idea to build it without any divisibility testing:

```
data Stream x = Cons x (Stream x) deriving (Eq)

streamRepeat x = Cons x (streamRepeat x)

interleaveStreams (Cons x xs) (Cons y ys) =
    Cons x (Cons y (interleaveStreams xs ys))

ruler =
    interleaveStreams (streamRepeat 0)
        (interleaveStreams (streamRepeat 1)
            (interleaveStreams (streamRepeat 2)
                (interleaveStreams (streamRepeat 3) (...))
```

where first 20 element of

```
ruler =
    interleaveStreams (streamRepeat 0)
        (interleaveStreams (streamRepeat 1)
            (interleaveStreams (streamRepeat 2)
                (interleaveStreams (streamRepeat 3) (streamRepeat 4))))
```

is

`[0,1,0,2,0,1,0,3,0,1,0,2,0,1,0,4,0,1,0,2]`

Obviously I couldn't define it manually to infinite so I defined a `infInterStream` to help such infinite recursion definition:

```
infInterStream n = interleaveStreams (streamRepeat n) (infInterStream (n+1))

ruler = infInterStream 0
```

But now I get stuck when typing in `ruler` in `ghci`, it probably falls into infinite loop.

It shouldn't be if lazy evaluation works. I want to know why lazy evaluation fails here.

---

Helper function to observe `Stream`:

```
streamToList (Cons x xs) = x : streamToList xs

instance Show a => Show (Stream a) where
    show = show . take 20 . streamToList
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Your interleaving function is too strict. The following works:

```
interleaveStreams (Cons x xs) ys = Cons x (interleaveStreams ys xs)
```

This also works:

```
interleaveStreams (Cons x xs) ~(Cons y ys) = 
    Cons x (Cons y (interleaveStreams xs ys))
```

The original definition goes into infinite loop because `interleaveStreams` demands that both arguments must be of `Cons` forms. `infInterStream n` evaluates to the the interleaving of two streams, and the first one can be immediately evaluated to `Cons`, but the second one must also be reduced  first to `Cons`, so we recursively call `infInterStream (n + 1)`, which keeps calling itself ad infinitum.

If `interleaveStreams` can return a `Cons a _` without first having to force the second argument, `infInterStream` can also incrementally build the result.

Comment: Your first definition looks very familiar that I must have seen it before. I guess it was in SICP

Answer (score 1):

There's no need for a new type for streams, and we can just use Haskell's lazy lists instead.  As others have noted, the definition of interleave must be sufficiently lazy that it can produce the first element of the output before testing whether the second argument is non-empty.  This definition will do:

```
interleave (x:xs) ys = x : interleave ys xs
```

If you want `interleave` to work also for finite lists, you can add the equation

```
interleave [] ys = ys
```

Note also that, using functions from the standard prelude,

```
ruler = interleave (repeat 0) (map (+1) ruler)
```

Here `repeat 0` is the list `[0, 0, 0, ...]`.

Comment: Using a separate stream type makes it locally obvious that pattern matches are complete, so I think it's better that way.

Comment: Yes, you can do that if you like: but then you need to redefine all the standard functions (like `repeat` and `map` above) for streams.  Compromise is the essence of engineering.

Comment: That's why we have Hackage! The code has already been written.

Comment: Why do I get the impression you are trying to pick a fight?

Comment: Not trying to pick a fight. It just looked to me like the OP set things up very nicely, and you seemed to brush that aside as extra work.